# MySQL Master-Slave replication installation on Windows with RAM Drive

Tags: mysql, master-slave, ramdrive

Interesting question I hope that someone can answer for me!

We have an application that uses MySQL enterprise, We are trying to see if it's possible to have a Master-Slave replication set up but using a RAM drive, The application being installed on the RAM drive(Z:) with a slave MySQL instance on the hard drive(C:).

This is using Windows.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so are there any resources available that I can be pointed to?

Thanks.

Comment: this is a very common operation. WHen you have a smaller dataset and plenty of ram that you can use where data can fit in. I work with linux and can create a drive/partition in ram and use it as a drive. So feel free to use it to store data. But if server is rebooted then you know what will happen.......